# Integrate with hospitals via FHIR - get access to hospital FHIR server

Tags: android, ios, healthkit, hl7-fhir

I would like to implement a feature for my app that allows user to import [FHIR](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/) data into my app. This is exactly same as [the new feature of Apple Health to import Health Records](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/01/apple-announces-effortless-solution-bringing-health-records-to-iPhone/)

I have read the FHIR specs as well as having the idea how to integrate with FHIR servers (my system contains iOS, Android and web app). The issue is: **how can I get access to hospital FHIR server (i.e: have OAuth credentials like app ID, app secret)? Do I need to contact each hospital to get them?**

Ideally, I would like to integrate with same hospitals in Apple Health list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be talking about US/Argonaut usage. At the moment, you need to contact the vendors - generally, the vendors are issuing application IDs and secrets for use in any hospital that they support

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, my application focuses on US.

Could you please list or recommend some vendors? I did a Google for it but not much useful information.

Comment: See the argonaut vendor list: http://argonautwiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=Main_Page/Background